# JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException when using text array from hibernate types

Tags: java, hibernate, h2

I'm using this [hibernate-types](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types) that allows hibernate to translate SQL layer data types into java classes in my springboot application, here I'm trying to add a text array field called user array.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_update")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@TypeDef(name = "list-array", typeClass = ListArrayType.class)
public class UserUpdate {

  @Id @NonNull private String userKey;

  @Column @NonNull private String userName;

  @Column @NonNull private Instant updatedAt;

  @Type(type = "list-array")
  @Column(columnDefinition = "text[]")
  @NonNull
  private List<String> userArray;
}
```

I can insert data into the table, but now I want to add a test and I see the following error message from the table.sql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_update (
    user_key VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    user_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    user_array TEXT ARRAY NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(org_key)
);
```

maybe it is because the test I'm running uses `@DataJpaTest` and for some reason it can not recognize the new text[] field ?

```
Error executing DDL "create table user_update (user_key varchar(255) not null, user_name varchar(255), user_array text[], updated_at timestamp, primary key (user_key))" via JDBC Statement

Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "create table user_update (user_key varchar(255) not null, user_name varchar(255), user_array text[*][], updated_at timestamp, primary key (user_key))"; expected "(, ARRAY, INVISIBLE, VISIBLE, NOT, NULL, AS, DEFAULT, GENERATED, ON, NOT, NULL, DEFAULT, NULL_TO_DEFAULT, SEQUENCE, SELECTIVITY, COMMENT, CONSTRAINT, COMMENT, PRIMARY, UNIQUE, NOT, NULL, CHECK, REFERENCES, ,, )"; SQL statement:
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? The error suggests H2, is that what you expect? If so, which version of H2 are you using?

Comment: I'm using com.h2database:h2:2.1.210 @MarkRotteveel

Comment: I think I am able to insert and read records with my model definition, but when I use @DataJpaTest in my integration test I see this error

Answer (score 0):

With `@DataJpaTest` Spring will instruct Hibernate to create the schema and that will use the information that you provided in your annotations, but it seems this is not legal for H2.

Try using the following instead:

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "text array")
```